# How can I mount filesystems with > 4KB block sizes?

Tags: linux, kernel, ext4, nas

I have a 3TB hard disk pulled out of a WD Mybook Live NAS. The partition table is as follows:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD30EZRS-11J (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 3      15.7MB  528MB   513MB                primary
 1      528MB   2576MB  2048MB  ext3         primary  raid
 2      2576MB  4624MB  2048MB  ext3         primary  raid
 4      4624MB  3001GB  2996GB  ext4         primary
```

So I'm trying to access partition 4 (the big one!):

```
root@john-desktop:~/linux-3.9-rc8# mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb4 /mnt/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb4,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Dmesg output:

```
[ 2058.085881] EXT4-fs (sdb4): bad block size 65536
```

This is fair enough. As far as I can tell my kernel isn't configured to support block sizes of over 4K.

My question is, what symbol should I be searching for in my kernel config to allow bigger block sized partitions to be mounted? I've scoured google for this, and I thought I saw the option before but I can't find any mention of it in the latest stable kernel source.

*Edit*: Full hard disk info from hdparm here: http://pastebin.com/hDdbUzjd

*Edit*: dumpe2fs output:

```
Mount count:              0
Maximum mount count:      30Last checked:             Wed May 30 15:22:14 2012Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)Next check after:         Mon Nov 26 14:22:14 2012Lifetime writes:          319 GBReserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      cd7a28a0-714c-9942-29f4-83bca1209130
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke
Journal size:             2048M
Journal length:           32768
Journal sequence:         0x00010146
Journal start:            0
```

Comment: Please note, passing a block size to the mount command does nothing: mount -t ext4 -o bs=65536 /dev/sdb4 /mnt .... the bs option is only supported on a handful of filesystems (and not ext ones..)

Comment: What is the `dumpe2fs -h` output for that volume? My 2012 man page for mke2fs says: "Valid block-size values are 1024, 2048 and 4096 bytes per block." Quite a jump from 4096 to 65536.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - Have added that output, thanks :)

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/246756/116326

Comment: @jofel that doesn't actually offer a solution, just a vague reasoning.

Comment: I'm currently trying a new kernel with 64k support by editing arch/x86/include/asm/page_types.h (#define PAGE_SHIFT      16 instead of #define PAGE_SHIFT      12)

Comment: Ok, that isn't going to work (fails compiling all over the place if you change that number). Maybe I can alter the block size on a file system using a tool of some kind?

Answer (score 26):

Woohoo, I solved it :)

The short answer is you can't mount >4k block size devices on x86 linux machines as far as I can tell without some serious kernel hacking.

However, there is a work around.. using fuse-ext2 to mount the disk:

```
fuseext2 -o ro -o sync_read /dev/sdb4 /mnt/
```

(you'll probably need to apt-get fuseext2 first..)

works perfectly first time!

This is basically going to be how people can recover their MyBook Live disks.

Howto blog post here: http://john-hunt.com/2013/04/25/recovering-data-from-a-wd-mybook-live-2tb-3tbor-similar/

Comment: Yea, the kernel page cache limits block size to the CPU's page size, so for i386/amd64, you can't mount a fs with more than 4k block size.  Another alternative is to use e2tools.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to access a Seagate Central NAS drive this way.

Comment: I try this way on 2 machines (kubuntu 14.04 x86 and 15.10 x64), but get freezing and CPU usage 100% by fuseext2 on open mount folder. Can me anybody say, why?

Comment: I'm getting a similar experience to YShinkarev - hanging when trying to access the fuseext2 mount, also freezes when I try to umount it. Ctrl+c has no effect...

Comment: While this does not answer the question per se, you can recover the data using `debugfs /dev/sdXX` where you can run basic commands such as `ls` and `rdump` to copy the files to a safe location. Source: http://n-dimensional.de/blog/2012/05/01/wd-mybook-live-data-rescue/ I used this method because the fuseext2 freezes (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=776248)

Comment: A version from Ubuntu repository worked very unstable for me until I built and installed it from source https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2

Comment: Apologies, the link is currently dead. Hopefully I'll recover it over the next couple of months.

Answer (score 3):

Some folks have experienced lockups with fuseext2, so here's an alternative:

```
debugfs /dev/sdb4
```

`debugfs` opens a CLI. `rdump <directory> <target>` will recursively copy an entire directory from the disk's filesystem to the host filesystem. For example, `rdump home /tmp` will copy the disk's `/home` directory to `/tmp/home`.

Comment: I did not get lockups with `fuse-ext2`. I was unable to mount at all. There was no error/debug output or logging either. Tried latest release from 2018 and also built from source using latest git branch. Thankfully, `debugfs` works perfectly fine, which is to be expected since it was created by one of the ext4 developers.